# How to manage RHEL patches in a production environment

Tags: linux, rhel, yum

My question is about what is redhat linux server patching process in production environment

I just know about `yum update` but how should it be done in production live environment?

Comment: Either create your own yum repo and manually manage it or use patch management software like satellite.  Question is fairly broad though.

Comment: Create a yum repo for each (monthly?) release you produced, labelled as such.  Point sets of production servers at that repo, do yum update, they all get to that same level of release that way.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the same patch level at the moment, you can save yum transaction on one host and transfer it to another [ just press N + Enter/return when asked to confirm], so loading this transaction will do the job without repo server/storage.

Also my suggestion is ''yum update -y'' for patching rhel, if no java specific apps, or all packages only from rhel repos.

All packages are tested good for general use.
if you have specific use, you know how to patch it =]